# Do you now how i can update a json in a function ? (API,Angular)

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api, service

So i have following JSON:

```
.json
"type": [ {
      "id": 2,
      "secondid": "1",
      "name": "f",
      "positionX": 0,
      "positionY": 0
}]
```

and following Service:

```
public updateposition(Model: typemodel): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.post(this.apiEndPoint + '/type' + '/' + typemodel.id , typemodel);
   }
```

and following TS:

```
.ts
 x: number;
 y: number;

updateposition()
{

}
```

So the goal is to update the json object "type" by clicking a button with html. The html part is no problem. But i don't know how to update the json object with the two new positions x and y which are declared in ts. I want to have the process in the function updateposition(). Do you have any suggestions :) ?

Comment: Why is `type` an array? It seems like the object you should be working with and updating is `type[0]`, not the array `type`. It seems like you were returned a JSON query with 1 result and didn't take out the first result (assuming it's a unique query that always returns 1 result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) to obtain a reference to the `Service` in your component and use it to retrieve and store the JSON object. Then update it like you would any other object in JS when the button is clicked, and make the API call. Be sure to subscribe to the result or the API call will not go through.

```js
// ...
export class MyComponent {
  public jsonObject: TypeModel = { ...  };
  public constructor(private service: Service) { }

  // ...

  public function updateposition() {
    this.jsonObject[0].positionX = 52;
    this.jsonObject[0].positionY = 42;
    this.jsonObject = this.service.updateposition(this.jsonObject).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log("The API call returned", result);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't completely understand the whole context of your question so I assumed you already had the data to put into the model? The `jsonObject` can be anything as long as it adheres to your description in the `TypeModel` type (in your question you seem to have flipped `Model` and `typemodel` sort of so I am confused what is what :)